# How does my Function know what Class it is receiving?

Tags: python, function, class, object

I am very new to Python and am just really digging into the whole class/object areas of understanding. Here is what I am really struggling with: if I have a class 'duck' with attributes and member functions in file duck.py and I am working with a function in witch.py that takes the duck class in. I issue the import statement

```
import duck
```

Then in my function:

```
def doesitfloat(myduck, mywitch):
    if myduck.boyancy() == 'floats':
    ...
```

how does the 'doesitfloat' know that myduck is a duck object with said attributes/member functions? I think I get the general concepts of classes, but when I create one, how do I use it elsewhere?

**Edit...**
My first post and new to python - what can I say.  Let me expound..

In my class file duck.py I have:

```
class duck:
    def buoyancy(self):
        return True
```

In another file witch.py I have my doesitfloat() function with appropriate import

```
import duck

def doesitfloat(myduck, mywitch)
    if myduck.buoyancy() == 'floats':
    ...
```

How does 'doesitfloat' know that myduck is an object or type duck?  Now, in another piece of code - maybe even in a third file, with appropriate imports declared I have the following:

```
someduck = duck
somewitch = witch  

testingsomething = doesitfloat(someduck, somewitch)
```

clearly the class is declared and locally in my third file I have declared the someduck and somewitch objects.  However, the function 'doesitfloat' is never really told that it is a duck object.  In other languages the declaration of 'doesitfloat' would explicitly state the type of the argument, but python...  ?? Sorry, this is just confusing to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you say `myduck = "quack"` then Python "knows" it's a string. If you say `myduck = duck()` then Python "knows" it's an object of the `duck` class. I don't see why either of these facts should be more mysterious than the other.

Comment: It doesn't "know". Either myduck will have a boyancy attribute that has a callable value, or an error will get thrown.

Comment: Objects carry type information with them. (Also, it's spelled "buoyancy". There's a "u".)

Comment: @RobinZigmond It doesn't really know, because it doesn't really care. The only thing the language cares about is that `myduck` is bound to *some* object, and will try to do whatever you ask it to do to or with that object; that attempt will either succeed or fail without ever looking at the type of the object.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, fair point - I used "know" just in the sense of "it can find these properties, but not these ones". Really my comment was inspired by my confusion that the OP was asking this question without apparently having bound the `myduck` variable to any value, and was trying to point out that there was nothing special here over the object being an instantiation of a user-defined class, as opposed to a member of a type built in to the language. It's certainly worth clarifying that the language doesn't "know" the type in advance, whereas in a statically-typed compiled language, it would.

Comment: @RobinZigmond My statement that Python tries "without ever looking at the type of the object" is also not entirely correct. It needs the type in order to know where to look for the attribute, of course, but it doesn't have any particular interest in what that type is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you have just realized one of the pointers in python, it's even called **duck programming** so to say *if it walks and talks like a duck, it is a duck*.

The program doesn't know earlier if a given object will have the said method, it tries accessing it (returning an error if it doesn't find).

It is up to the developer using the code to adhere to the purpose of the code.

In python when you try running `myduck.boyancy()` python tries access the `boyancy` attribute/method of the object being referenced by the variable `myduck` and if it doesn't find any attribute/method it will return an error.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a dynamically typed language.

In many languages you would have to explicitly declare a type with the variable, such as in C#:

```cs
Duck duck = new Duck();
...
duck = new Frog(); // This throws an error in a statically typed language
```

In python every variable is a reference to a python object. These objects know their own type and contain the properties and methods of the class or primitive they are constructed from.

```python
duck = Duck()
...
duck = Frog() # This changes the duck variable to reference a new Frog object instead
```

If you try to access a member of an object that does not exist, python will throw an error.

You can check if a variable actually references a Duck using the `isinstance()` function:

```python
if isinstance(duck, Duck):
    # ... now we know duck is a Duck or Duck sub-class
```

Comment: Variables don't have type; they are just names that refer to arbitrary objects that know their *own* type. You aren't really changing the type of a variable, because it never had a specific type in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will improve the answer.